# How to get the data for each tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this page to get data of each Ad:
http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/?

each Ad is in a class called content, so i wrote a for loop to get all content classes, then get the data of each content "Ad" desperately, but i get the data of all content in each loop iteration. here is my code in scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell "http://www.cars2buy.co.uk/business-car-leasing/Abarth/695C/"
for content in response.xpath('//*[@class="pitem"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]'):
          print content.xpath('//*[@class="detail"]/p/text()[2]').extract()
```

but the output is:

```
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
[u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 48 months', u' 36 months']
```

which means that it get data for all the tags in each iteration!!
I need the output to be:

> ```
> 48 months
> 48 months
> 48 months
> 36 months
> 48 months
> 48 months
> 48 months
> 48 months
> 48 months
> 36 months
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get data of each ad you can use following code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for detail in response.xpath('//div[@class="detail"]/p'):
        item = dict()
        item['term'] = detail.xpath('text()[2]').extract_first()
        item['mileage'] = detail.xpath('text()[4]').extract_first()
        item['payment'] = detail.xpath('text()[6]').extract_first()
        item['fee'] = detail.xpath('text()[8]').extract_first()
        yield item
# {'term': ' 48 months', 'mileage': ' 10,000', 'payment': ' £2,227.86 + VAT', 'fee': ' &pound249.00 + VAT'}
```

Note you need to use `extract_first()` method since `extract()` return a list.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, i did not used extract_first() before. that is what i really need thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: Could you please check this, too. I tried it with a different class, but it only get the first item in each iteration: here is my code:
`for content in response.xpath('//*[@class="pitem"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]'):
print content.xpath('//*[@class="content"]/div[1]/div[2]/p/text()[2]').extract_first()`
the output in all is 48 months!

Comment: I'm sorry for late response. I can't understand why you are using autogenerated xpath expression but not a xpath from my answer? My xpath expression works and provides expected [output](http://icecream.me/00860bf2ce5f659898b4f0c7eab15362). If you want to scrape more info from ads (e.g. `h1` or monthly price or link) you could adjust xpath to: `//div[@class="box"]/div[@class="content"]`  [Output](http://icecream.me/bbd91999c9a679a421e698de9e4d05ec).

Answer (score 0):

you could directly use xpath to select the element with class="detail", change your code like this:

```
In [5]: for content in response.xpath('//*[@class="detail"]/p/text()[2]').extrac
t():
   ...:     print content
   ...:
 48 months
 48 months
 48 months
 36 months
 48 months
 48 months
 48 months
 48 months
 48 months
 36 months
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that, but i can not do a for loop for each piece of data.